# Story about boy raised by two necromancers/warlock/dark wizards

Tags: story-identification, books

I can't find the story I read which is about a boy raised by two male dark wizards in a kingdom where dark wizards are hunted.

> He meets a princess that escaped and I think one of his foster parents die in the end.

Comment: _This_ should not be the one marked as a dupe... FuzzyBoots question came a lot later and that is the one that should be marked as a dupe!

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath Age of a question shouldn’t matter, close to quality not age. Also not much point reopening just to change the dupe direction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is [**The Dark Wizard Of Donkerk**](http://www.alexanderwales.com/darkWizardNaNo2016.html) (written by Alexander Wales as part of [NaNoWriMo](https://nanowrimo.org/how-it-works)).

---

**Boy raised by two dark wizards**

> *It didn’t occur to him that perhaps he had been right in wanting to stay, even if is reasoning was clouded.*
>
> ***And so it was that the orphan was raised by two dark wizards.***

Comment: *Golf clap* nice find.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast - In fairness it was quite a good (if terse) description.